# How to make mathematica give 1/0 as infinity

Tags: function-construction, trigonometry

I would like Mathematica to print $\arctan(4/0)$ as $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but it does not because in mathematica 1/0 is complexinfinity. How do I make it print n/0 as Infinity so that Arctan will give me what I want?

Comment: Why positive infinity? Why not `DirectedInfinity[-1]`? For `ArcTan`, why not `-Pi/2`?

Comment: Actually yeah I would like it to be positive or negative infinity depending on sign of n.

Comment: $\frac{4}{0} = {\infty}_{+}$ when $`` 0 "$ is infinitesimally positive ("_positive zero_"), but not when it's  infinitesimally negative ("_negative zero_") nor perfectly zero (integer-zero).  So it'd seem like, for this to be a correct result, you'd need to clarify what $`` 0 "$ means in that expression.

Comment: @Nat, this is where it'd have been nice to have a "signed zero" like in IEEE's model, but alas...

Comment: @user, then you should indeed be using two-argument arctangent in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the off chance that what is desired in a computational environment in which `n/0` evaluates to (positive) `Infinity` and `t = ArcTan[..]` falls in the range `-Pi/2 <= t <= Pi/2`.  One should use caution when overwriting built-in functions.  I doubt this will cause problems in computations in which `n/0` should always mean positive `Infinity` and not `ComplexInfinity`.

```
ClearAll[evaluateWithRealPower];
SetAttributes[evaluateWithRealPower, HoldFirst];
evaluateWithRealPower[code_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Power},
   Unprotect[Power];
   Power[0, p_?Negative] := Infinity;
   Power[0., p_?Negative] := Infinity; (* optional *)
   Protect[Power];
   code];

evaluateWithRealPower[ArcTan[4/0]]
(*  \[Pi]/2  *)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

Use the two-arg version of [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan) instead:

```
ArcTan[0, 4]
```

> π/2

Comment: ...and if you also need to evaluate at `0, 0`, you could use `Arg[x + I y]` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can convert expressions of `ComplexInfinity` to `Infinity` by using the `ReplaceAll` operator `/.`.

```
ArcTan[4/0 /. ComplexInfinity -> Infinity]
```

which gives `Pi/2` as output.